# Logs for GCP network load balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm working with GKE cluster. In gke I have microservices that are using GRPC. Also I have an ingress that deployed under GCP NLB. *I'm aware about gcp ingress but it's not the best option for my case.*

Most of the services have long living connections(15m+). And during the test I found that all long living connection drops after 30s or more. I suggest that it may be timeouts on the LB level.

Is it possible to find NLB logs somewhere to ensure that connection drops on LB level?

Comment: Please check this [document](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/quotas) and Backend services overview [document](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service).

Comment: Hi'I've checked the link but didn't find information related to the question

Comment: You can use non-neg and use node based LB and use GKE taints to keep pods grouped together on certain nodes then LB that way, It has its own risks as some nodes will be hit more heavy than others (hence why neg is a thing) but it allows you to artificially create affinity pod groups if you evenly distribute your pods to different nodes, then you can probably get the taints and the lb working fine with the affinity on the node instead of the pod. Please refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/internal/internal-logging-monitoring).